# Ler .txt, setar delimitador, remover duplicadas

Tags: php

Boa tarde. Preciso que meu script leia um .txt como o do exemplo abaixo:

```
4984538078766798|11|2016|246 
// Na primeira linha $a teria o valor de "4984538078766798"
// $b teria o valor de 11
// $c teria o valor de 2016
// $d teria o valor de 246
4108637744329741|07|2017|241
// Na segunda linha $a teria o valor de "4108637744329741"
// $b teria o valor de 07
// $c teria o valor de 2017
// $d teria o valor de 241
4984012022438078|08|2016|757 
// Na terceira linha $a teria o valor de "4984012022438078"
// $b teria o valor de 08
// $c teria o valor de 2016
// $d teria o valor de 757
```

Ignorar linhas vazias e remover as duplicadas.

Já tentei desta seguinte forma e não obtive sucesso:

```
    $list = dirname(__FILE__) . "/lista.txt";

$content = file_get_contents($list);
$txt = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$separa = trim('|', $txt);
$a = trim($separa[0]);
$b = trim($separa[1]);
$c = trim($separa[2]);
$d = trim($separa[3]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de se evitar a duplicidade de elementos é usar o elemento como índice de um array. Assim, toda vez que você jogar um mesmo índice nele, ele será desconsiderado. 
Sendo assim, pelo que entendi de sua pergunta você quer duas coisas:

1. Desconsiderar linhas duplicadas
2. Ter um 'campo' para cada valor encontrado, devidamente 'explodido' com o delimitador '|'

O exemplo abaixo faz isso (você também pode testar em https://ideone.com/DfPnqn):

```
<?php
$linhas = array('123|45|1234|101', '999|88|777|666', '123|45|1234|101');
foreach ($linhas as $linha)
    $arr[$linha] = NULL; // aqui se removem as linhas duplicadas
echo "*** LINHAS ***\n";
foreach ($arr as $key => $valor) { 
    echo $key . "\n"; // aqui se comprova o resultado final sem duplicatas
    $partes = explode ('|', $key);
    foreach ($partes as $parte) {
        $var[$parte] = NULL; // aqui se cria um array que resume todos os números sem duplicatas
    }
}
echo "*** CAMPOS ***\n";        
foreach ($var as $key => $valor)
    echo $key . "\n"; // aqui se comprova o resultado de todos os campos finais sem duplicatas
```

Como não tenho seu arquivo, simulei 3 linhas dentro de um array:

```
$linhas = array('123|45|1234|101', '999|88|777|666', '123|45|1234|101');
```

No seu caso, basta desconsiderar o código até a linha 4, mas inserir a linha lida em `$arr[$linha] = NULL`.

Ao executar, resulta em:

```
*** LINHAS ***
123|45|1234|101
999|88|777|666
*** CAMPOS ***
123
45
1234
101
999
88
777
666
```

Como pode perceber, todos os dois arrays que usei recebem NULL pois não têm necessidade de armazenar nada neles, foram usados apenas para retirar as eventuais duplicidades.

https://ideone.com/DfPnqn

Comment: Muito obrigada por tentar ajudar, amigo :)

Comment: @Gennie, aí você está usando o separador ';' e o seu enunciado você usou '|'.

Comment: Não está claro como está seu arquivo txt, como é cada linha, ficará mais fácil se você editar sua pergunta original e colocar lá umas duas ou 3 linhas originais.

Comment: Sim, irei fazer isto agora mesmo.

Comment: Pronto amigo :)

Comment: Ok, agora entendi. No seu programa, você está lendo TODO o arquivo para dentro de uma string usando `file_get_contents`. Se você quer processar CADA LINHA individualmente, você pode ler com `fgets` como neste exemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_file_feof. Daí, a cada linha você pode fazer o `explode` e pegar os 4 pedaços, colocando-os nas variáveis desejadas.

Comment: Consegui, amigo, obrigado. Como eu posso fazer para contar quantas linhas tem no meu txt ?

Comment: Preciso criar uma variável para contar as linhas, para enquanto tiver linhas restantes no txt ele executar o restante do código e quando não tiver mais linhas restantes ele parar.

Comment: Fiz desta maneira: `$myfile = fopen($ccs_list, "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$ccs = fgets($myfile);
$partes = explode('|', $ccs);
$cc = trim($partes[0]);
$b = trim($partes[1]);
$c = trim($partes[2]);
$d = trim($partes[3]);`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78507/discussion-between-rogerio-dec-and-gennie).